# Overwrite "single-product" block template in WooCommerce for some products only

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, block, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a couple of products, I need to render another block template than `single-product.html`, i.e. `single-product-custom.html`.

The problem is, that there doesn't seem to be a similar logic to select templates like in pages or a way through the website editor to just add a template for products in a specific category.

Answer (score 0):

**Filter meta field**

Custom templates in pages are stored in a meta field `_wp_page_template`.

It is possible to filter this field for a custom value, like:

```
add_filter('get_post_metadata', function ($value, $object_id, $meta_key, $single, $meta_type) {
   if($meta_key === '_wp_page_template' &&  /** Other conditions to match **/) {
         return 'single-product-custom';
   }  
   return $value;
}, 10 , 5)
```

**Use ACF to select meta field**

Another easy solution is to use Advanced Custom Fields and add a select box to set this field, with at least two values: `single-product` and `single-product-custom`